# HTML replace Font tag

Tags: html, fonts, deprecated

I have read that the Font tag has been deprecated since 2013.
What tag should I use instead? 
For example, how should I replace this:

```
<Font Face="Arial", size=+1, Color=#FF0000>
   <p>some text here
</Font>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use css to style your content. Like so:

```
<p style="font-family:Arial; font-size:2em; color:#ff0000;">some text here</p>
```

Comment: João Silva is searching a solution to avoid deprecated tag. I think he's searching good practices. Using a style attribut is not a good practice. Daniel_ZA posts a best answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a `<span>` div with a CSS class.

**CSS**

```
.font-class{
  font-family:Arial; 
  font-size:2em; 
  color:#ff0000;   
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="font-class">
  some text here
</span>
```

I find this much neater than inline styling